# AWS Cloudwatch custom metrics using powershell throws error

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-cloudwatch

I am configuring custom cloud watch metrics for windows ec2 instance. The command which I use to invoke the script manually is

```
C:\Cloudwatch\Memory.ps1 -aws_credential_file C:\Cloudwatch\awscreds.conf -mem_util -mem_used -mem_avail -memory_units Kilobytes
```

For all the other ec2 instances which I did execute this command gave me the exact result, but this instance gives me the error

```
A WebException with status NameResolutionFailure was thrown.
```

There are no issues with setting up the region or accesskey_secretkey. FYI, the region is us-east-1 (N.Virginia). Can anyone please help me at the earliest. Any support would be really appreciated.

Comment: A NameResolutionFailure sounds like a DNS lookup; either something named by hostname which you can't get to, a misconfigured DNS server, or maybe a typo in a server name in the script or credentials file ... ?

Comment: Double check your region string as a sanity check anyway; that's the exact error thrown when something's wrong with the region.  More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30430119/775544